# How do I avoid jvm running compiler threads in the jvm container

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

How do I avoid jvm running compiler threads in the jvm container.

```
"C1 CompilerThread1" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fb2980cc000 nid=0x440e waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #5 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fb2980be800 nid=0x440d waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid them?

Answer (score 2):

Those threads are from the hotspot compiler. If you want to get rid of them in the thread dump, start your application as `java -Xint ...`.

Be warned it might run slowly afterwards. ;-)

**edit** To make it clear. Disabling the JIT compiler is not something you want to do. As then the bytecode is executed in `interpreted` mode instead of `compiled code for your plattform`. see [java options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

small snippet for demonstration

```
public class Jit {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10_000_000; i++) {
            sb.append(' ');
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("length = " + sb.length());
        System.out.println("duration: " + (end - start));
    }
}
```

run in mixed mode (compile on demand)

```
java Jit
length = 10000000
duration: 124
```

run in interpreted mode

```
java -Xint Jit
length = 10000000
duration: 3495
```

Comment: Might?  Will!  By an order of magnitude!

Comment: @StephenC I know. Therefore the smiley.

Comment: I know you know.  But the OP probably won't "get" your humor.

Comment: @StephenC Valid point. I add more explanation and a small snippet for demonstration.